# Iphone to Ipad programming and submitting

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I recently finished an app that I worked on. Only for iphone. But i've had problems lately submitting this app to itunes. According to them the app crashes immediately during launch. I've tested and tested on many iphones and could no get it to crash.

Then finally I tried ipad. I must've missed this one and never went in my head. When I made my app I chose only for iPhone. But I guess iTunes/apple wants it for both Ipad and Iphone. Now I have my app set on universal which works for both devices.

My problem is that when i launch my app onto the ipad, my app only shows in small resolution and it's in on the top left corner of the ipad's screen. My app works except when the user has to pick a picture from his library. Normally on the iphone this works with no problem. But the ipad crashes...

My question is that, is there any easy way to make my app work on the ipad just the way it works on the iphone? I really don't know how else I can ask this question.

EDIT** Crash report**

> Incident Identifier: D1256273-2E53-4AE9-8CA4-6272B6C32B32
>
> CrashReporter Key:   bd45bf94d4b469ecf708d7d00f434f15d8ac4273
>
> Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
>
> Process:         SSRWheels [7615]
>
> Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/80DF85DD-CDD2-4579-BE8E-
>   D23715385446/SSRWheels.app/SSRWheels
>
> Identifier:      SSRWheels
>
> Version:         ??? (???)
>
> Code Type:       ARM (Native)
>
> Parent Process:  launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:       2012-01-04 11:34:55.728 -0800
>
> OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
>
> Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x00000000,
>   0x00000000 Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow''
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x3455a8bf 0x359751e5 0x3455a7b9 0x3455a7db 0x32cbe747 0x32cbfbb9 0x32bf8a45 0x32a82227 0x32a7c313
>   0x32a4a921 0x32a4a3bf 0x32a49d2d 0x30d9cdf3 0x3452e553 0x3452e4f5
>   0x3452d343 0x344b04dd 0x344b03a5 0x32a7b457 0x32a78743 0xa2aaf
>   0xa2a68)

Answer (score 3):

> But I guess iTunes/apple wants it for both Ipad and Iphone. Now I have
>   my app set on universal which works for both devices.

Your app doesn't have to be universal, but it does have to run on the iPad in compatibility mode. From the [App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone
>   resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

If you're going to make your app universal, you'll need to do some extra work to make it adjust to the available screen size and function properly as an iPad app. No matter what you do, you should definitely test on an iPad (as you've discovered). I'd skip the universal app, at least for now, and go back to making a iPhone app. Find and fix whatever problems occur on the iPad in compatibility mode, and you'll soon have an app that you can submit successfully. Once you've got your app in the App Store, you can spend some time reworking it to make it universal.

Comment: Okay gotcha... I put it back to iphone and it seems like it's running good on the ipad. But here's the deal. The first time I ran my app on the ipad, it did crash immediately, during launch. Then when I put my app on universal mode it worked. After reading your reply, I put it back to iphone target and the app ran like it should. I never really found out why the app crashed during launch.

Comment: @Nakioki I sympathize -- it's awfully frustrating to face a bug that's difficult to reproduce. The best advice I can think of is to try to reproduce exactly what you did when it crashed. Delete the app from the device, reinstall, perform the same actions... anything that'll get it to crash again. Figuring out how to reproduce the bug is the first step toward fixing it.

Comment: Thank you. And yes before I resend the app to itunes. I'll do my best to recreate this "crashing" problem. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: After coming back from a long vacation. It seems like apple has rejected my app once again. I tried my best to recreate the crashing they told me about on the crash report. But my app does not crash on Iphone and iPad (1 and 2). It's getting really frustrating... I've updated my first post showing the crash report. Again, the app is only for iPhone only. But I made sure that the app also works on the Ipad.

Comment: At least you've got a crash report to work with. Now you need to symbolicate the report so that you can see what code is causing the error. [Move your crash report into the Device Logs section of Xcode's organizer.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW5)

Comment: how do I actually see what's causing it, once it's on the device log?